# Security type issue when creating an azure machine from a legacy image in powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I'm trying to automate the creation of machines from a master image and to do this I'm creating images of the OS disk.
When I try to create a new machine I always get the same error.

Image creation :

```
$randomInt = Get-Random -Minimum 1000 -Maximum 9999
$masterVM = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $masterNameVM
$masterImageName = "MASTER-IMAGE-" + (Get-Date -Format 'dd-MM-yy') + "-" + $randomInt
$masterImageConfig = New-AzImageConfig -Location $location -HyperVgeneration "V2" 
$masterImageConfig = Set-AzImageOsDisk -Image $masterImageConfig -OsState "Generalized" -OsType "Windows" -ManagedDiskId $masterVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.ManagedDisk.Id
$masterImage = New-AzImage -ImageName $masterImageName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Image $masterImageConfig
```

VM Creation :

```
for ($i = 1; $i -le $machineCount; $i++) {
    $tmpName = $sessionHostNamePrefix + "-" + $i

    $pip = New-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -Name "$tmpName-pip" -AllocationMethod Static -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 4 -Force
    $nic = New-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -Name "$tmpName-nic" -SubnetId (Get-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vnetName).Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id -NetworkSecurityGroupId (Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $nsgName).ResourceId -Force

    $tmpConfig = New-AzVMConfig -VMName "$tmpName-Vm" -VMSize $masterVM.HardwareProfile.Vmsize
    $tmpConfig = Set-AzVMOperatingSystem -VM $tmpConfig -Windows -ComputerName $tmpName -Credential $creds -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate
    $tmpConfig = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $tmpConfig -Id $nic.Id
    $tmpConfig = Set-AzVMSourceImage -VM $tmpConfig -Id $masterImage.Id
    $tmpConfig = Set-AzVmUefi -VM $tmpConfig -EnableVtpm $true -EnableSecureBoot $true;
    $tmpConfig = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $tmpConfig -Name "$tmpName-OsDisk" -Caching "ReadWrite" -CreateOption "FromImage" -Windows
    $tmpConfig = Set-AzVMSecurityProfile -VM $tmpConfig -SecurityType "TrustedLaunch"

    New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -VM $tmpConfig -Verbose -Zone $masterVM.Zones 
}
```

Output :

```
New-AzVM: 
Line |
  15 |      New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -VM $tmpC …
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Resource 'LP-AVD-1-OsDisk' should have same Security type as the source resource 'MASTER-IMAGE-01-12-23-2727_0_crctds5jdgw'.
ErrorCode: OperationNotAllowed
ErrorMessage: Resource 'LP-AVD-1-OsDisk' should have same Security type as the source resource 'MASTER-IMAGE-01-12-23-2727_0_crctds5jdgw'.
ErrorTarget: /subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/LP-AVD-1-OsDisk
StatusCode: 409
ReasonPhrase: 
OperationID : 722167e4-83ae-4caf-8f33-bda5dfe522ec
```

Value of $masterVM.SecurityProfile.SecurityType : TrustedLaunch

I'm totally lost. Can someone explain me what i missed ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: At first glance it looks like recycling $tmpConfig and using it for different things might give unexpected results.  Have you set breakpoints on each `$tmpConfig =` line and inspected `$tmpConfig` with Get-Member or anything like that?

Comment: @Paulπ I checked the final result and it looks good too. I also tried using the strict minimum parameters and the result is the same unfortunately

Comment: I would still set breakpoints, maybe use VSCode, and inspect each line and object to be certain that the properties are being set the way you're intending them.  Take all of this out of the loop real quick and attempt to create a single AZ VM using explicit values.

Comment: I agree @Paulπ: try `Set-StrictMode -version latest` and see if you get a different error/hint, or completely (try) to rebuild the `$tmpConfig` in the `for ($i ...` block to exclude the suggestion.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help but unfortunately using "Set-StrictMode -version latest", the error remains the same.
And even when rebuilding my VM, the problem is the same. I've checked each line :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the cause of my problem.
It's actually not possible to create a VM from a "Trusted Launched" SecurityType image.
I realized this by changing the order of my functions and modifying them slightly.

Another problem is that it's not possible to transform a VM, a disk or a snapshot from SecurityType "Trusted Launched" to Standard.
I hope this helps others.